# Custom text field autocorrection

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8

Is it possible to customize the autocorrection of the keyboard when entering text into a text field?

In my app, I have a text field where rather long technical terms have to be entered. If I could provide an additional dictionary with frequent terms, it would incredibly help my users.

I've searched the documentation of the current iOS version and had a peek at the new iOS 8 documentation. QuickType seems similar to what I'm looking for. But is it configurable?

I hope it's doable without creating a custom keyboard. I don't think that's the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

No, at the moment of writing it is simply not possible to add or alter the autocompletion or autocorrect library that Apple uses in combination with it's keyboards. Apple just doesn't allow "tampering" with it's autocompletion/correction and probably for good reason since they are context aware and self learning.

Alternatives you can consider:

*1. Create your own keyboard with your own "quick type"*

Probably not the best option, since you don't want to alter the keyboard but only autocompletion.

*2. Add some kind of autocompletion in your app*

There are some autocomplete libraries you could look into like [HTAutoCompleteTextField](https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTAutocompleteTextField) and there are probably other [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org) you could look into. I think this would be your best option.

You could also write some sort of autocomplete yourself that shows the options while you type in a table or other kind of UI if you can't find a library that suits you. Not trivial, but could be worth it for your users.